# Indent clojure on Emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I am trying to set up the emacs to have auto-Indentation for clojure code.

Until now unsuccessful. What is the command to set into the config file for that?

Comment: What did you try? What went wrong and how?

Comment: i have in my init.el file (amongst other things) : `(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
  '("melpa-stable" . "http://melpa-stable.milkbox.net/packages/") t)`.  and under `(defvar my-packages` also `clojure-mode` which i think brings per default indentation? but its still everything unindented if i am working on a .clj file, so i should set the indentation manually with tab.

Comment: Did you read cider instruction? It is very powerful and, de facto, default environment for clojure in emacs with nice documentation.

Comment: yes i have read it and most of its parts work also for me. But in the autocompletion part i have installed company-mode it says in the documentation: `To make tab complete, without losing the ability to manually indent, you can add this to your config:

(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") #'company-indent-or-complete-common)
`. So i added this line to my init.el, but there is still no indentation.

Comment: So complete works on "tab" and (cider-jack-in) was done without errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample emacs config for what i consider the "minimal" usable emacs config for Clojure. I say minimal in that I'm not willing to work without good code completion, jump to definition, project aware file handling etc:

from [this example](https://github.com/tanzoniteblack/basic-clojure-emacs) which you can clone to ~/.emacs.d:

This is just a hilight, see the init file in the example project for the context, **look at the project for recent versions, etc. don't just copy these**:

```
(use-package clojure-mode
  :ensure t
  :config
  (add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'yas-minor-mode))

(use-package cider
 :ensure t
 :config (progn (add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'cider-mode)
                 (add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'cider-turn-on-eldoc-mode)
                 (add-hook 'cider-repl-mode-hook 'subword-mode)
                (setq cider-annotate-completion-candidates t
                       cider-prompt-for-symbol nil)))

;; clojure refactor library
;; https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clj-refactor.el
(use-package clj-refactor
  :ensure t
  :config (progn (setq cljr-suppress-middleware-warnings t)
                 (add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook (lambda ()
                        (clj-refactor-mode 1)
                        (cljr-add-keybindings-with-prefix "C-c C-m")))))
```

there is also some code to add to ~/.lein/profiles.clj:

```
{:user {:plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.10.0-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [refactor-nrepl "1.1.0"]]
        :dependencies [[acyclic/squiggly-clojure "0.1.3-SNAPSHOT"]]}}
```

Comment: i have actually a set up with which i can work very good, except that there is no indentation activated, i have paredit, cider, eldoc, company, projectile as minor modes and clojure-mode of course, but i couldn't find anywhere in google about  a command, package which enables auto-indentation. I know there are some methodes to indent manualy, `Cx Tab` etc., but this is cumbersome to do every time!

Comment: as a test: if you put this config in place of yours, does autocomplete work? then put half of it inplace and test again ... bisect. this may lead to the difference that is breaking it. if indention does not work even with this config that would be another clue.

Comment: i tried it, doesn't work. Is it not so that the auto-indentation actually is  included in clojure-mode?

Comment: i have also added tests like (put-clojure-indent '-> 1) to my init.el as said here: https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode, still no indentation

Comment: yes, indentation is included in clojure-mode by default, lets dig into the input side of things, perhaps the tab keys are not getting to emacs in the correct form. If you put mark and point around some code, and run M-x indent-region and it all jumps to the correct indentation then start trying to figure out what function is actually being called when the tab key is pressed M-x describe-key TAB and see that it's calling a reasonable function.

Answer (score 0):

I added

`(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)`

to the `init` file and this worked. I am not sure if this was the best solutaion, but it did the trick.

Comment: That key is often bound to Ctrl-j with enter being the non-indented version.